# Express deprecated req.param(name): Use req.params, req.body, or req.query instead

Tags: node.js

I am newbie to node.js and have developed the following application. In this application I am expecting value 'isAdmin' : true in reponse, but I dont get it. Instead I see the following error Why ?

```
express deprecated req.param(name): Use req.params, req.body, or req.query instead app.js:34:22
express deprecated req.param(name): Use req.params, req.body, or req.query instead app.js:35:26
```

Something certainly is missing out. Please guide.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');


var app = express();
//app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));


function authUser(request, response, next){
    var user = {
        name : 'Raj',
        admin : true
    };

    request.user = user;
    next();
};

app.use(authUser);

app.get('/', function(request, response){
    response.send({
        foo : 'bar',
        person : 'Raj',
        isAdmin : request.params.user.admin
    });
});


app.post('/doStuff', function(request, response){
    var param = request.param('foo');
    var firstName = request.param('firstName');
    response.send({
        foo : param,
        firstName : firstName
    });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

[image]

Comment: http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.params

Comment: isAdmin : request.params.user.admin - also dont get worked. Updated post above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `req.params('firstName')` is deprecated as of [Express v4.11.0](https://github.com/expressjs/express/releases/tag/4.11.0)

You should be using standard object dot notation `req.params.firstName` instead.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.user = {
        name : 'Raj',
        admin : true
    };

    return next();
});

app.get('/',(req, res) => {
    return res.send({
        foo : 'bar',
        person : 'Raj',
        isAdmin : req.user.admin
    });
});

app.post('/doStuff', (req, res) => {
    return res.send({
        foo : req.params.foo,
        firstName : req.params.firstName,
        isAdmin: req.user.admin
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I am looking to get response like below
{
    "foo": "bar",
    "firstName": "firstName",
    "isAdmin" : true
}

Comment: @user4798115 updated to use the user middleware in the question